# Pass authentication from SharePoint online to web app silently

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, sharepoint, office365

I want to build the web application which passes the authentication from SharePoint 365 to web application.The flow is the user opens SharePoint online and clicks a link to this website the authentication is passed silently.

My web application front end is angular 6 and back-end is developed by asp.net web api

Any help will be really appreciated
Thanks,
Erandika

Comment: Please add things like what all have you tried so far, if you have done some code for it, please consider adding your implementation to the question as well.

Comment: I couldn't find any thing related to this one.it is possible with SharePoint api. But I want silent login and I couldn't find any resource related to this one in google.